# Reaching a point B in Cartesian coordinate via Euler angles knows its initial point A Euler angles and B Euler angles

Tags: coordinate-systems, angle

I have a point A:

Known it's Cartesian coordinates (X,Y) and its Euler angle Aka head rotation (R,P) respectively Roll (rotation around X axis) , Pitch (rotaion around Y axis). (I'm not using Yaw because i'm working in graphics 2D)

Now I have a point B:-

Knows its Euler Angles only (X',Y') .

What I need to find is the coordinates of the point B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct the rotation matrix corresponding to your yaw and pitch, and multiply the vector by the rotation matrix to have it rotate by the right amount.

However, in general, I would *always* recommend [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) over euler angles. They're a mathematical formalism and aren't super intuitive at first, but they let you avoid some *nasty* problems with Euler angles (most famously, the loss of one degree of freedom which is called as "gimbal lock")